# GraphQL - Best way of passing credentials

Tags: graphql

If I have a GraphQL query/mutation and need to pass login information, how should I do it? Should I pass it in the query itself or pass it into the headers of the request? For example:

```
doSomethingThatRequiresLogin(
  login: {
    username: "some username",
    password: "c29tZSBwYXNzd29yZA=="
  },# should login be passed here or just put into the headers?
  data: {
    a: "b"
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login credentials should be put in the `argument` like so:

```
mutation Login($password, $username) { // put credentials here
  login(password: $password, username: $usernameOrEmail) {
    // belows are the field you want to return after user login
    user {
        username  // return username is generally a common practice
        token     // just like what we usually do in a REST api
    }             // return the things client mutated/updated
    errors{
        ...
        // alternatively return a optional errors field
        // when things go south
    }
  }
}
```

In you graphql server, you can access the credentials through args:

```
async function login(parent, args, context, info) {
  const {username, password} = args // we get the credentials here

  ...  // your password hashing and db stuff

  return {
    token,
    user
  };
}
```